# Radio Button не работает в Bottom Sheet во Flutter

Tags: flutter

У меня есть modal bottom sheet, в котором есть два radio button. Но при нажатии они не работают. Я не знаю в чем проблема, думаю, дело в том что radio button находится в bottom sheet.

> Вот мой код

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NutritionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NutritionScreenState createState() => _NutritionScreenState();
}

class _NutritionScreenState extends State<NutritionScreen> {
  double height = 500.0;
  TextEditingController textFieldControllerAge = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController textFieldControllerGrowth = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController textFieldControllerWeight = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController textFieldControllerWeightGoal = TextEditingController();
  bool _validateAge = false;
  bool _validateGrowth = false;
  bool _validateWeight = false;
  bool _validateWeightGoal = false;
  // Declare this variable
  int selectedRadioTile;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedRadioTile = 0;
  }

  setSelectedRadioTile(int val) {
    setState(() {
      selectedRadioTile = val;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textFieldControllerAge.dispose();
    textFieldControllerGrowth.dispose();
    textFieldControllerWeight.dispose();
    textFieldControllerWeightGoal.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _modalBottomSheetMenu() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (builder) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .viewInsets
                    .bottom),
            child: new Container(
                height: height,
                color: Colors
                    .transparent, //could change this to Color(0xFF737373),
                //so you don't have to change MaterialApp canvasColor
                child: new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                          topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "Питание",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 26.0),
                              )),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextField(
                                maxLines: 1,
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                controller: textFieldControllerAge,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                                    fontSize: 18.5),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0),
                                  labelText: "Возраст",
                                  errorText: _validateAge ? 'Поле должно быть заполненным' : null,
                                  alignLabelWithHint: false,
                                ),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                              )),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextField(
                                maxLines: 1,
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                controller: textFieldControllerGrowth,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                                    fontSize: 18.5),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0),
                                  labelText: "Рост",
                                  errorText: _validateGrowth ? 'Поле должно быть заполненным' : null,
                                  alignLabelWithHint: false,
                                ),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                              )),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextField(
                                maxLines: 1,
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                controller: textFieldControllerWeight,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                                    fontSize: 18.5),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0),
                                  labelText: "Вес",
                                  errorText: _validateWeight ? 'Поле должно быть заполненным' : null,
                                  alignLabelWithHint: false,
                                ),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                              )),
                          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextField(
                                maxLines: 1,
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                controller: textFieldControllerWeightGoal,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                                    fontSize: 18.5),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0),
                                  labelText: "Целевой вес",
                                  errorText: _validateWeightGoal ? 'Поле должно быть заполненным' : null,
                                  alignLabelWithHint: false,
                                ),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                              )),

                          RadioListTile(
                            value: 0,
                            groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
                            title: Text("Мужчина"),
                            onChanged: (val) {
                             setSelectedRadioTile(val);
                            },
                            activeColor: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                            selected: true,
                          ),
                          RadioListTile(
                            value: 1,
                            groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
                            title: Text("Женщина"),
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              setSelectedRadioTile(val);
                            },
                            activeColor: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                            selected: false,
                          ),

                         Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                              child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                                      heroTag: "tag4",
                                      backgroundColor: Color(0xffFF7070),
                                      child: Icon(
                                          Icons.check, color: Colors.white),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          textFieldControllerAge.text.isEmpty ?
                                          _validateAge = true : _validateAge = false;

                                          textFieldControllerGrowth.text.isEmpty ?
                                          _validateGrowth = true : _validateGrowth = false;

                                          textFieldControllerWeight.text.isEmpty ?
                                          _validateWeight = true : _validateWeight = false;

                                          textFieldControllerWeightGoal.text.isEmpty ?
                                          _validateWeightGoal = true : _validateWeightGoal = false;
                                        });
                                        if(textFieldControllerAge.text.isNotEmpty &&
                                            textFieldControllerGrowth.text.isNotEmpty &&
                                            textFieldControllerWeight.text.isNotEmpty &&
                                            textFieldControllerWeightGoal.text.isNotEmpty)
                                          _sendDataToSecondScreen(context);

                                      }))),

                        ],
                      )),
                )),
          );
        });
  }

  void _sendDataToSecondScreen(BuildContext context) {
    String textAge = textFieldControllerAge.text;
    String textGrowth = textFieldControllerGrowth.text;
    String textWeight = textFieldControllerWeight.text;
    String textWeightGoal = textFieldControllerWeightGoal.text;
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) =>
              MainNutrition(
                  textAge: textAge,
                  textGrowth: textGrowth,
                  textWeight: textWeight,
                  textWeightGoal: textWeightGoal),
                // Этого класса нет
        ));
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff2b2b2b),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen[400],
        title: Text(
          'Питание',
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 45.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 200.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Нажми на кнопку, чтобы добавить правильный рацион питания.",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                )),
            FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: "tag3",
                backgroundColor: Color(0xffFF7070),
                child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {
                  _modalBottomSheetMenu();
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы радиокнопки в modal bottom sheet обновлялись, нужно использовать `StatefulBuilder`

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, state) {
```

и в обработчиках кнопок использовать новый метод `state` (по сути тот-же setState, только переименован)

```
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          state(() {
                            selectedRadioTile = val;
                          });
                        },
```

Весь код здесь:

```
class NutritionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NutritionScreenState createState() => _NutritionScreenState();
}

class _NutritionScreenState extends State<NutritionScreen> {
  double height = 500.0;
  TextEditingController textFieldControllerAge = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController textFieldControllerGrowth = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController textFieldControllerWeight = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController textFieldControllerWeightGoal = TextEditingController();
  bool _validateAge = false;
  bool _validateGrowth = false;
  bool _validateWeight = false;
  bool _validateWeightGoal = false;
  // Declare this variable
  int selectedRadioTile;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedRadioTile = 0;
  }

  setSelectedRadioTile(int val) {
    setState(() {
      selectedRadioTile = val;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textFieldControllerAge.dispose();
    textFieldControllerGrowth.dispose();
    textFieldControllerWeight.dispose();
    textFieldControllerWeightGoal.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _modalBottomSheetMenu() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, state) {
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                child: new Container(
                    height: height,
                    color: Colors
                        .transparent, //could change this to Color(0xFF737373),
                    //so you don't have to change MaterialApp canvasColor
                    child: new Container(
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                              topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                "Питание",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 26.0),
                              )),
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextField(
                                maxLines: 1,
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                controller: textFieldControllerAge,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                                    fontSize: 18.5),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0),
                                  labelText: "Возраст",
                                  errorText: _validateAge
                                      ? 'Поле должно быть заполненным'
                                      : null,
                                  alignLabelWithHint: false,
                                ),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                              )),
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextField(
                                maxLines: 1,
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                controller: textFieldControllerGrowth,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                                    fontSize: 18.5),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0),
                                  labelText: "Рост",
                                  errorText: _validateGrowth
                                      ? 'Поле должно быть заполненным'
                                      : null,
                                  alignLabelWithHint: false,
                                ),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                              )),
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextField(
                                maxLines: 1,
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                controller: textFieldControllerWeight,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                                    fontSize: 18.5),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0),
                                  labelText: "Вес",
                                  errorText: _validateWeight
                                      ? 'Поле должно быть заполненным'
                                      : null,
                                  alignLabelWithHint: false,
                                ),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                              )),
                          Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextField(
                                maxLines: 1,
                                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                controller: textFieldControllerWeightGoal,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                                    fontSize: 18.5),
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4.0),
                                  labelText: "Целевой вес",
                                  errorText: _validateWeightGoal
                                      ? 'Поле должно быть заполненным'
                                      : null,
                                  alignLabelWithHint: false,
                                ),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                              )),
                          RadioListTile(
                            value: 0,
                            groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
                            title: Text("Мужчина"),
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              state(() {
                                selectedRadioTile = val;
                              });
                            },
                            activeColor: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                            selected: true,
                          ),
                          RadioListTile(
                            value: 1,
                            groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
                            title: Text("Женщина"),
                            onChanged: (val) {
                              state(() {
                                selectedRadioTile = val;
                              });
                            },
                            activeColor: Colors.lightGreen[400],
                            selected: false,
                          ),
                          Container(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                              child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                                      heroTag: "tag4",
                                      backgroundColor: Color(0xffFF7070),
                                      child: Icon(Icons.check,
                                          color: Colors.white),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(() {
                                          textFieldControllerAge.text.isEmpty
                                              ? _validateAge = true
                                              : _validateAge = false;

                                          textFieldControllerGrowth.text.isEmpty
                                              ? _validateGrowth = true
                                              : _validateGrowth = false;

                                          textFieldControllerWeight.text.isEmpty
                                              ? _validateWeight = true
                                              : _validateWeight = false;

                                          textFieldControllerWeightGoal
                                                  .text.isEmpty
                                              ? _validateWeightGoal = true
                                              : _validateWeightGoal = false;
                                        });
                                        if (textFieldControllerAge
                                                .text.isNotEmpty &&
                                            textFieldControllerGrowth
                                                .text.isNotEmpty &&
                                            textFieldControllerWeight
                                                .text.isNotEmpty &&
                                            textFieldControllerWeightGoal
                                                .text.isNotEmpty)
                                          _sendDataToSecondScreen(context);
                                      }))),
                        ],
                      )),
                    )),
              );
            }));
  }

  void _sendDataToSecondScreen(BuildContext context) {
    String textAge = textFieldControllerAge.text;
    String textGrowth = textFieldControllerGrowth.text;
    String textWeight = textFieldControllerWeight.text;
    String textWeightGoal = textFieldControllerWeightGoal.text;
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Container()
            // MainNutrition(
            //     textAge: textAge,
            //     textGrowth: textGrowth,
            //     textWeight: textWeight,
            //     textWeightGoal: textWeightGoal),
            // Этого класса нет
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xff2b2b2b),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen[400],
        title: Text(
          'Питание',
          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 45.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 200.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Нажми на кнопку, чтобы добавить правильный рацион питания.",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                )),
            FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: "tag3",
                backgroundColor: Color(0xffFF7070),
                child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {
                  _modalBottomSheetMenu();
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[источник](https://github.com/Ephenodrom/Flutter-Advanced-Examples/tree/master/lib/examples/managingInputsWithinModalBottomsheet)

Comment: @MIT источник указал.

Answer (score 0):

Полностью рабочий пример. Из-за того что вы не предоставили часть кода <s>(А я не Ванга)</s>, могу предположить что проблема кроется в другом месте.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

int selectedRadioTile = 0;

@override
void initState() {
  initState();
  selectedRadioTile = 0;
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Title"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            new RadioListTile(
              value: 1,
              groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
              title: Text("Radio 1"),
              onChanged: (val) {
                print("Radio Tile pressed $val");
                setState(() => selectedRadioTile = val);
              },
              activeColor: Colors.lightGreen[400],
              selected: true,
            ),
            new RadioListTile(
              value: 2,
              groupValue: selectedRadioTile,
              title: Text("Radio 2"),
              onChanged: (val) {
                print("Radio Tile pressed $val");
                setState(() => selectedRadioTile = val);
              },
              activeColor: Colors.lightGreen[400],
              selected: false,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

### UPD

Проблема заключается в том, что `showModalBottomSheet` не обновляет своё состояние, для решения этой проблемы рекомендую посмотреть [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52414629/how-to-update-state-of-a-modalbottomsheet-in-flutter).
На самом деле ваши `radio button` обновляют своё значение, но так как нет обновления виджета `showModalBottomSheet` это не отображается. Это можно было заметить и визуально, и при помощи `print("Radio Tile pressed $val");`.
Также рекомендую выносить повторяющийся код в отдельные методы, это сократит ваше время в дальнейшем.

Comment: Сейчас скину весь код

Comment: @CyberDemon и отредактируй его, для более удобного копирования.

Comment: @CyberDemon обновил ответ.